# Concatenate two data-frames (dask) with the same number of partitions but different number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have two data-frames with the same number of partitions. I want to concatenate these data-frames (first partition with first partition, the second one with the second one, etc.) Therefore, the final data-frame has the initial number of partitions (`V`), the same number of rows in every partition (`n`) but a different number of columns (sum of the number of columns of data-frame one and data-frame two `(n+m)`). The first data frame (`A`) has a timestamp as an index but the second one (B) doesn't have this column. Both data-frames are sorted, and I only need to put these data-sets together without any change in every partition. Also, the index for `A` will be the index for the new data-frame.

```
A: data-frame (V partitions) - every partition (nXn)
B: data-frame (V partitions) - every partition (nXm)

C (new data-frame): (V partitions) - every partition (nX(n+m))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not too hard:

```
C = dd.from_delayed([dask.delayed(pd.concat)([a, b])
    for a, b in zip(A.to_delayed(), B.to_delayed())],
    meta=A._meta)
```

explanation

- get the partitions of each dataframe as delayed objects
- pass pairs of these to `concat`
- form the concatenated pairs back into a dataframe
- reuse meta, since the output has the same columns and index as the inputs

(C is, of course, still lazy, the operation will only be triggered when you do something to it)

Comment: I think I am concatenating on rows, but you wanted on columns - but you get the idea